# Ideas for parsing a text file in C#

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm wondering what would be the best way to parse this format:

```
map=
{
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {1,1,1,1,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
    {2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,1,1,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,1,1,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,1,1,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,4,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,1,1,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,7,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,7,2,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,1,1,1,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,1,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,7,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
    {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}
}
```

... into row, column and number format?

Comment: One might say that it's already in a row/column format: map[10,10] = 0

Comment: It's map format for my 2d game.

Comment: It took me a while to see it, but now I see the side-scroll layout in the numbers. Pretty cool.

Comment: I don't really get the question. Do you want a nice way to represent this in a text file, and a way to parse that file into the 2d array?

Comment: Judging from the accepted question and other responses, this question has nothing to do with "parsing".  It appears he is just asking how to index into his array by row and column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really need "parsing" it's already in a nested Array.

So you can use it using standard for loops:

```
for (int row = 0; row < map.Length; row++)
{
  for (int col = 0; col < map[i].Length; col++)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(map[row][col]);
  }
}
```

And access any specific row by:

```
int rowNum = 5;
int colNum = 2;
Console.WriteLine(map[rowNum][colNum]);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are the one making that map, then why not change your format to something more parse-able? It seems to me that just using ascii characters would be easiest, and then just parse it char by char into an array. probably easier to generate the map this way anyway.

```
..................................
......**************..............
.....******************...........
....***********************.......
....w******w************xx*.......
```

etc..

Comment: How is that any more parsable than an array of numbers?

Comment: each char here is an element in the resulting map. in the OP's format, it's 1) difficult to read, and 2) there are a bunch of extra characters (mostly commas and whitespace). A text file is already a 2D array, so might as well take advantage of this similarity. And replace numbers with symbolic characters to make it more visual, just as a bonus.

Comment: it's possible i misunderstand the OP. i assumed he's parsing a text file consisting of `map={.....}`. Considering the answer he accepted, it looks like this wasn't a question of parsing at all.

Answer (score 0):

For flat files i normaly use the http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/filehelpers.aspx.

It might help you on this one...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the C# code to create a multidimensional array?  Here is the one for your example.

int[,] map = new int[25,100] { ... your array goes here... }

Answer (score -1):

The map in the example is JSON.
Just use a JSON deserialiser. For example:
http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/112-JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-Net.aspx

Comment: it can be parsed as a JSOn array ;)